# If statement to check Excel cells in a Macro

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a If statement that checks if a given cell exists (some are merged) and has a value different of '-', a statement is executed, in this case a query.
In case the conditions are not met, the query is not executed

```
CellStr = Range("C3").Text
If CellStr <> "-" Then
Set rs = conn.Execute("QUERY")
End If
```

The code I present works when the cell has value '-' (the query does not execute), but does not work when the cell does not exist (the query executes and returs a 0)

How can I protect the If Statement against this issue?

Comment: Try `If CellStr <> "-" And CBool(Len(CellStr)) Then`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the cell exists (i.e. is not covered by merged cells) before you check the value/text in the cell:

```
Sub test()

    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("C3") 'Set the cell

    'Check if the cell exists, i.e. is not covered by merged cells
    If c.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Address = c.Address Then

        'Check if the cell text is different from "-"
        If c.Text <> "-" Then

            'Execute something
            MsgBox "Put your statement here"

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Best regards,

Simon